# how to stop closing the excel until the validation is met using vb script

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I want to perform a validation on a column. The validation is that X should start with 0.

When data is entered and when closing the excel sheet, it should throw an error message saying the data is incorrect and it should not allow me to close until and unless I correct the data.

I have put the code in Before Close. It is showing the error message if data is incorrect, but closing before we change the incorrect data.

Also tried with Before save. It is same behaviour found.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks,
Jaya Vignesh Kannan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the Workbook_Before_Close macro has a 'Cancel' parameter. You could then do something like this:

```
Dim isValid As Boolean

' Calculate isValid however you'd like

If Not isValid Then
    MsgBox "This is my invalid message!"
    Cancel = True 'Cancel workbook close
End If
```